# Cakephp check if model exists

Tags: cakephp, model, exists

I am creating an application in which I am using two plugins. 
For future use I want to check whether the two plugins are being used together or separately.
I need to check if the model exists and if so perform some logic and if not - not.
If I try if($this->loadModel('Model')) { etc }
I get an error saying the model does not exist which is what I want but I don't want an error which prevents the logic from proceeding.

Basically I want:

if(Model->exists()) { do->this }
else { do->somethingelse }

I tried using the php function class_exists() but that returns false regardless of whether the Model exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `App::objects('model')` as of 2.x (Not sure when this was implemented).

```
class AppController extents Controller {   
   private function _modelExists($modelName){
      $models = App::objects('model');
      return in_array($modelName,$models);
   }    
}

//Somewhere in your logic
if($this->_modelExists('SomeModel')){
   //do model exists logic
} else {
   //do other logic
}
```

*Note that `App::objects('model')` will not include models from plugins. You could do:

```
$models = array_merge(
   App::objects('model'),
   App::objects('MyPlugin.model')
);
```

You can also do this with pure php as follows

```
if(class_exists('SomeModel')){
   //do model exists logic
} else {
   //do other logic
}
// The pitfall of this approach, is that it will not assure 
// that `SomeModel is a decedent of the `Model` class.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init("User");
```

if $model is null this means that the User model does not exist
You can do this from every where in the code

Comment: actually its never null!
its the AppModel if the Class cannot be found.

you need to check with App::import() which returns a boolean value of success

Comment: wrong, this init a new class, anyway it doesn't match necessary with your declared model

Comment: mark's comment is correct.  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382631/how-to-check-if-model-exists-with-cakephp for a more detailed answer.