# How to check if Model exists with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I dynamically load models in a general-purpose function and I noticed that sometimes I want to skip loading models because it raises a 404 error.

How can I check if the model exists?

Something like:

```
if($this->modelexists($type) {
  $this->loadModel($type);
} else {
  return "xxx";
}
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you running?

Comment: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/How-to-tell-if-a-model-exists-td1317657.html

Comment: this does not solve the problem because if i try to init a model that does not exists, it still return a 404

Comment: i would just go through models dir and check if file exist :) combined with class_exist

Comment: i don't think it's the safest way to do that but i will take it into consideration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you haven't specified your version, I've split my answer in two, one for 1.3 and one for 2.0.

**CakePHP 1.3**

The `loadModel()` method will return false if it cannot find the model, see the [API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Controller.html#_loadModel). So just check it doesn't return false like:

```
if(!$this->loadModel($type)) {
    return "xxx";
}
```

**CakePHP 2.0**

If the model class does not exist, the `loadModel()` method will throw a `MissingModelException`, so just catch that.

See the [API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-MissingModelException.html) on this.

Example:

```
try {
    $this->loadModel($type);
} catch(MissingModelException $e) {
    // Model not found!
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Note that `loadModel()` only exists in controllers.  Anywhere else, use `App::import()` as answered by mark below.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2.x, despite the docs saying it does. Docs here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Controller.html#_loadModel say an exception is thrown and $this->loadModel() will return false. However on further inspection I found a Cake PHP issue referring to this which says the docs are wrong: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3664-Controller-loadModel-not-throwing-MissingModelException

Comment: The docs are wrong in the sense that the model will always be found because CakePHP generates them dynamically if there's no model file. Personally, I find this very annoying. In many cases, you can work around it by catching a `MissingTableException` instead.

Answer (score 4):

CakePHP 2.x

```
function model_exists($type){
  $model_list = array_flip(App::objects('model'));
  return isset($model_list[$type]);
}
```

You can add this to AppController and use in combination with **&__get()** to auto-load the model if you like. In that case you may want to use a member variable (e.g. $this->model_list) to save the list so you don't have to call App::objects() each time.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small tweak to Adam's function to allow for plugins as well:

```
  public function modelExists($modelClass, $plugin=null){
    $object = 'model';
    if($plugin){
      $object = $plugin.'.'.$object;
    }
    $model_list = array_flip(App::objects($object));
    return isset($model_list[$modelClass]);
  }
```

One problem remains. It does not seem to pick up models in the Lib/Model directory.

Have not been able to solve this yet. Will update post if I find a solution.

---

I just added support for the lib directories

I also merged the plugin and modelClass vars.(can be called as array or string for convenience sake)

Here is the new function:

```
  public function modelExists($modelClass, $checkLoaded=true){
    $modelClass = !is_array($modelClass)?$modelClass:implode('.', $modelClass);//implode if is array
    list($plugin, $modelClass) = pluginSplit($modelClass, true);
    $plugin=rtrim($plugin,'.');
    $object = 'model';
    if($plugin){
      if($checkLoaded){
        if(!CakePlugin::loaded($plugin)){
          return false;
        }
      }
      $object = $plugin.'.'.$object;
      $libPaths = App::path("Lib/Plugin/$plugin");
    } else {
      $libPaths = App::path('Lib');
    }
    $list = App::objects($object, null, false);

    foreach($libPaths as $path){
      $libModels = App::objects('lib.'.$object, $path.'Model'.DS, false );
      if(is_array($libModels)){
        $list = Hash::merge($list, $libModels);
      }
    }
    if(in_array($modelClass, $list)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Usage:

it can be called like so:

$this->modelExists('SomeModel');

$this->modelExists('Plugin.SomeModel');

$this->modelExists(['SomeModel']);

$this->modelExists(['Plugin', 'SomeModel']);

//Note use array( ) instead of [ ] if you expect to deploy on php version < 5.4

Answer (score 0):

for 1.3 you can use

```
App::import('Model', 'ModelName');
```

which returns false if it does not exist

For 2.x I didnt find a working solution yet

Answer (score 0):

this works for me as for cake 2

```
if (in_array($model, App::objects('Model'))) {
    $this->loadModel($model);
} else {
    return 'error';
}
```

by `App::objects('Model')` it returns all the model names as array